# How to detect and report on-page network errors such as Image and JavaScript load failures using JavaScript?

Tags: jquery

I have requirement to capture and report all network errors(403 & 404) i.e Image, JavaScrpit other resource loading failures. we have tried

```
window.addEventListener('error', function(e) {
    console.log(e);
}, true);
```

and window.onerror but no luck as the above two solutions work any JavaScrpit errors but doesn't deal with resource loading failure.

We are looking for a solution which works for cross origin as well.

[what we need to capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgTrR.png)